# I want to edit the checkout field from the WooCommerce admin edit page

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have added some custom fields on the WooCommerce checkout page. I have saved the data of those fields and displayed it on the admin order page. Like picture no.1. Everything is OK.

Now I want to edit the data/text/value of this field. Like picture no.2. Like billing and shipping on the admin order page....

How can I solve it?

```
function display_admin_order_meta ( $order ) {
$strt= $order->get_meta('_checkout_custom_name', true );
if( ! empty( $strt) ){
    $label = __( 'Phone' );
    if( is_admin() ){ 
        echo '<p><strong>' . $label . ' : </strong> ' . $strt. '</p>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<table class="woocommerce-table"><tbody><tr>
            <th>' . $label . ' : </th><td>' . $strt. '</td>
        </tr></tbody></table>';
    }
}

$strt= $order->get_meta('_checkout_others_address', true );
if( ! empty( $strt) ){
    $label = __( 'Address' );
    if( is_admin() ){ // Admin
        echo '<p><strong>' . $label . ' : </strong> ' . $strt. '</p>';
    }
    else {
        echo '<table class="woocommerce-table"><tbody><tr>
            <th>' . $label . ' : </th><td>' . $strt. '</td>
        </tr></tbody></table>';
    }
}
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address', 'display_admin_order_meta', 20, 1);
```

[image]

This is the checkout field data I created. I want to edit these like the picture above.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is a way(customize it if needed)

Add custom billing form data input with woocommerce_admin_billing_fields filter

```
add_filter('woocommerce_admin_billing_fields', 'add_woocommerce_admin_billing_fields');
function add_woocommerce_admin_billing_fields($billing_fields) {
    $billing_fields['_checkout_custom_name'] = array( 'label' => __('Name', 'woocommerce') );
    $billing_fields['_checkout_others_address'] = array( 'label' => __('Address', 'woocommerce') );

    return $billing_fields;
}
```

Then save custom fields like this

```
function cloudways_save_extra_details( $post_id, $post ){
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_checkout_custom_name', $_POST[ '_checkout_custom_name' ] ) );
    update_post_meta( $post_id, '_checkout_custom_address', $_POST[ '_checkout_custom_address' ] ) );
}
add_action( 'woocommerce_process_shop_order_meta', 'cloudways_save_extra_details', 45, 2 );
```

Comment: Thank you. First, I didn't want to add any new fields. I just want to edit the data that I saved from the checkout page field and show it in the admin panel. Second, I don't want to edit inside the billing field. I want to edit the data on the order page from where it is.

Comment: Display custom data in input filed where define woocommerce_admin_order_data_after_billing_address hook, then save order like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45833977/woocommerce-admin-order-edit-save-post

Comment: That's good. But I'm thinking a little differently. The code you provide only works on the Amin panel. What is the way to display its output on my account page or anywhere else?